# Changing the font in a UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts, tabbar

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me with a problem I am having at the moment. I a m trying to change the actual font of the `UITabBar`, I have been able to chance the text colour and the colour when the text is selected. The code i have so far is here:

```
//Setting tab bar background
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
//[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]];

// Changes Selected Image color
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:33.0/255.0 green:35.0/255.0 blue:38.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //Icon colour

// Changes StateNormal text Color,
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:214.0/255 green:69.0/255 blue:65.0/255 alpha:1.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //Colour of text when not seleted

// Changes StateSelected
UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; //Colour of text when selected

[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : titleHighlightedColor} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I was wondering if anyone would know if it is possible to change the font here and if so how i would come across doing so? The code is located in the AppDelegate.m

Thanks in advance,
Harrison

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it to the title text attributes:

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes: @{
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:214.0/255 green:69.0/255 blue:65.0/255 alpha:1.0],
  NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]
} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Hmm never mind that...this should work, are you seeing any changes at all? Is the font color working?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:5.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Have you typed the font name correctly? and does xcode support that font? @BadfishLabs

Comment: The font i chose is supported by Xcode yes as i have used it before i added the font as a target and went into the Plist and added it in there too.

Comment: @BadfishLabs I have just tested it myself and it is working fine, Have you put this code in your app delete under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: I will test this now again, if this doesn't work would you be able to talk to me over Skype or another program to show you? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked either :( Maybe you could take a look over Skype or Join.me?

Comment: @BadfishLabs Yeah i could look for you

Comment: My Skype is Harrison.Badfishlabs

Comment: @BadfishLabs I am at work at the minute but i will be able to look at it around 5:30 - 6:45 tonight?

Comment: Sorry i missed the message, i'm available now if you would want to take a look?

Comment: @BadfishLabs Im on now, i have sent you a contact request